# Is it possible to set the width of one cell alone without affecting other cells in phpExcel?

Tags: php, pdf, phpexcel

Is it possible to set the width of one cell alone without affecting other cells?

I am generating a pdf file using phpexcel.

I need to set the width of cell A1 to 40.
Tried this
     $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getColumnDimension('A')
    ->setWidth(40);

It does affect the entire column .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't, in exactly the same way that you can't in MS Excel, Open/Libre Office Calc, or in Gnumeric.... PHPExcel tries to replicate the functionality of these spreadsheet packages, not the tables in Word.

You can, perhaps, merge cells to achieve what you want

Answer (score 0):

it seems you cannot change individual cell see https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/discussions/448594

not sure if it fits your need , anyway you can remove the right border from cell so that two adiacent cells looks like one,  as shown in this code